# How to use Angular data within a quoted string

Tags: javascript, string, angularjs

**Briefly**: I am trying to pass a string to an angular function on ng-click. The string needs to have embedded data within it from the angular world (the string is composite of a a static fragment and an Angular 'variable')...

```
<button ng-click="hello('Mr/Ms {{name}}')">Test</button>
```

**Problem**: I can't seem to make angular switch back and parse the brackets as anything other than a string. So, how do  I fix/reaarange/modify the string so that the embedded Angular content is passed within the string on ng-click.

**Desired Outcome**
On success I should see a javascript alert stating "hello Mr/Ms Samuel"

**Plunkr** ...
http://plnkr.co/edit/vKMCpAjfXbYZtNgxqubv

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent" ng-controller="test">
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <button ng-click="hello('Mr/Ms {{name}}')">Test</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var app = angular.module("app",[]);

    app.controller("test",function($scope){
      $scope.name="Samuel";
      $scope.hello=function(val){
        alert("hello " + val);
      };
    });

    angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

});
```

Comment: ng-click="hello('Mr/Ms '+name)"

Comment: I knew it would be simple, please post as answer.

Comment: So, anyone care to elaborate as to why a minus 1 ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use classic javascript variable, not an angular expression

```
ng-click="hello('Mr/Ms '+name)"
```